# 301 Redirects not performing as expected

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

we're migrating domains and *some* but not all content. The URL structure is different.

Below is what I have in my .htaccess file. I only added the code at the end starting with "#User added 301 Redirect", the other entries were in .htaccess already.

Expected/Desired: I want anyone who goes to the old main domain to the new main domain, and anyone who attempts to access these specific pages of the old site/domain to go to the mapping in the new site.

Observed: the main domain 301 works olddomain.com now goes to newdomain.com, or if the file name/path is exactly the same. Redirects follow he taxonomy of the old domain, not use my mapping. So, "olddomain.com/about-me" tries to go to "newdomain.com/about-me" instead of the correct mapping "newdomain.com/about" as shown in the .htaccess file and results in a 401 file not found error.

Thoughts? Feel free to respond like I'm five years old.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF

# User Added 301 Redirect
Redirect 301 / https://newdomain.com/
Redirect 301 /paleo-salmon-cakes https://newdomain.com/blog-entries/paleo-lemon-ginger-salmon-cakes
Redirect 301 /organic-vs-conventional https://newdomain.com/blog-entries/organic-vs-conventional-produce
Redirect 301 /endocrine-disruptors https://newdomain.com.com/blog-entries/what-are-endocrine-disruptors-and-why-you-should-care
Redirect 301 /vegan-paleo-caesar-dressing https://newdomain.com/blog-entries/avocado-cashew-caesar-salad-dressing-vegan-and-paleo
Redirect 301 /about-me https://newdomain.com/about
Redirect 301 /contact https://newdomain.com/contact
Redirect 301 /work-with-me/business-client-services https://newdomain/for-businesses
Redirect 301 /work-with-me/individual-client-services https://newdomain.com/for-individuals
Redirect 301 /work-with-me/pregnant-postpartum https://newdomain.com/for-individuals
Redirect 301 /spinach-banana-muffins https://newdomain.com/blog-entries/spinach-banana-muffins
# User Added 301 Redirect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try redirect directives in following order:

```
# User Added 301 Redirect
#Redirect 301 / https://newdomain.com/
Redirect 301 /paleo-salmon-cakes https://newdomain.com/blog-entries/paleo-lemon-ginger-salmon-cakes
Redirect 301 /organic-vs-conventional https://newdomain.com/blog-entries/organic-vs-conventional-produce
Redirect 301 /endocrine-disruptors https://newdomain.com.com/blog-entries/what-are-endocrine-disruptors-and-why-you-should-care
Redirect 301 /vegan-paleo-caesar-dressing https://newdomain.com/blog-entries/avocado-cashew-caesar-salad-dressing-vegan-and-paleo
Redirect 301 /about-me https://newdomain.com/about
Redirect 301 /contact https://newdomain.com/contact
Redirect 301 /work-with-me/business-client-services https://newdomain/for-businesses
Redirect 301 /work-with-me/individual-client-services https://newdomain.com/for-individuals
Redirect 301 /work-with-me/pregnant-postpartum https://newdomain.com/for-individuals
Redirect 301 /spinach-banana-muffins https://newdomain.com/blog-entries/spinach-banana-muffins

#
# this as the last line:
#
Redirect 301 / https://newdomain.com/

# User Added 301 Redirect
```